# ArrayList<CustomClass>を保存して、次回起動時に読み出したい

Tags: android

intとStringの２つのメンバ変数をもったオリジナルクラスItemを作成しました。
MainActivityでは、Itemのリストを作成しています。

Item.java

```
public class Item{

int id;
String name;

Item(int id,String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Item item1 = new Item("111","TANAKA");
Item item2 = new Item("222","MATUMOTO");
Item item3 = new Item("333","UEDA");
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemList.add(item1);
itemList.add(item2);
itemList.add(item3);
```

上のitemListはアプリが起動している間は使えますが、
アプリが終了すると空になってしまい、次回起動時には使えません。
ArrayListを保存して、永続化させる方法をご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JacksonやGSONを使ってjsonに変換し、PreferenceやSQLiteに保存する方法はいかがでしょう？